# 3d Hilbert Curve for a sparse geometry

Tags: optimization, cuda, opencl, hilbert-curve

I have a 3d array containing the non-cubic bounding box of a sparse geometry.

The array geometry[x][y][z] contains the value 0 if (x,y,z) is part of the computational domain and otherwise 1.

In an attempt to reorder computations I would like to traverse this space using a Hilbert Curve.

The context is optimizing global memory access in a memory-bound GPU program.

How can I implement this?

**Update**:
I just want to traverse the non-empty cells, as I will only store those (in an array) together with an adjacency list which keeps track of an element's 19 neighboring nodes.

The computation is simply copying between two arrays:

```
dst[i] = src[adjacency_map[i]]
```

This is the propagation phase of a sparse Lattice Boltzmann method, where the physical interpretation is streaming 'fluid particles' from a neighboring site.

The more sequential the values in adjacency_map are; the more coalesced memory accesses we hopefully get.

OpenCL kernel:

```
__kernel void propagation(__global double *dst, __global double *source,
                          __global const int *adjacency_map, const uint max_size)
{
    size_t l = get_global_id(0);

    if( l > max_size ) 
        return;

    dst[l] = src[adjacency_map[l]];
}
```

Comment: do you want to traverse **all** the cells of the volume, or just the non-empty cells? What computation do you wish to apply to the cells?

Comment: i want to traverse only the non-empty cells as they will be later stored in an array. I've updated the original question with some more information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A Hilbert curve would be a tall order.  It seems difficult to find a formulation that would allow random access to the indices of the points on the curve.

A [Morton ordering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-order_curve), however, would be reasonable, and has some of the same nice properties as it is also a space-filling curve.  There is also a random access procedure for finding the Morton number of an N-dimensional point.

What you might consider is a two step process:

1. Apply a step of stream compaction to your data to select the volume elements that you wish to process
2. Sort this compacted data, using their [Morton indices as the sorting key](http://mgarland.org/files/papers/gpubvh.pdf).

You could use [thrust](http://code.google.com/p/thrust/) for both the stream compaction and the key-value sort.

This should produce a list of volume elements in a ordering which promotes contiguity. That said, the overhead of reorganizing the data may dominate the cost of the original irregular access pattern.

Answer (score 1):

That sounds quite impossible.

Did you already rule out a kdtree or octree?

The descriptions of kdtree (chapter 21.2) and octree (chapter 21.8) in numerical recipes are quite understandable:
http://apps.nrbook.com/rollover/index.html